# How can I make text not responsive?

Tags: css, html

I want to have my texts keep all its formatting no matter the size of the screen, however if I were to make the screen small enough it will change its format to fit the screen.

How can I make it so it just stays in its original position and formatting.

```html
<div style="background-color: white; height: 600px; padding: 100px 200px;">

  <br><br><br>

  <h1 style="font-size: 70px;color:#21ce99;">about me</h1>

  <p style="font-size: 20px;color: #0ec998">I'm a Developer and aspiring Entrepreneur <br>from Voorhees, New Jersey in the US.</p>
  <p style="font-size: 16px;color: #0ec998">As a young developer, I strive to make complex <br>problems, simple. Combined with my passion <br>for entrepreneurship, I hope to create something<br>that can beneficially impact the world.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `white-space: nowrap;` to the container.

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b2dbyjgx/1/**

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving them a minimum width and height by using min-width and min-height properties in your style tags. Make sure not to use relative units of measure such as vh, em, or rems use pixels instead to ignore screen size completely. You should put these properties on the div that surrounds your text.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign the text you don't want to wrap the CSS' white-space property.

Answer (score 0):

The **white-space property** specifies how white-space inside an element is handled.

Sequences of **whitespace** will collapse into a single **whitespace**. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a **< br >** tag is encountered.

Now for more of text properties you can refer : [W3school White-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

```css
p{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p>Your desired textYour desired textYour desired textYour desired textYour desired textYour desired textYour desired textYour desired text</p>
```